# How to change Path of CSS File in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to change the folder name of my Sub-directories of CSS file. For Example, currently it is in `/pub/static/version1584394723/frontend/MTheme/layout/en_US/calendar.css`. But I want to make my **Mtheme** folder name to be changed to say **Ztheme**

i.e `/pub/static/version1584394723/frontend/**ZTheme**/layout/en_US/calendar.css`

I have simply changed the folder name, but that didn't work.  Apart from changing folder name, I guess I need to change the href also. But don't know how to do that. Can anyone tell me how to edit href?

Comment: Do you understand how to create a child theme? Ztheme would be a child of Mtheme. Then through backend configure site to use Ztheme.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you must do:

1. Change the folder name as you did but it's

`app/design/frontend/your_theme`

2. Change the title of the theme in file `theme.xml`

(`app/design/frontend/yourtheme/theme.xml`)

3. Clear cache and static files, folders in

`pub/static`

4. Run 2 command lines :

   > php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   >
   > php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ( -f if you are magento 2.2 or later )
5. Go to backend and change configuration to use the new theme.
6. Clear cache and refesh your frontend.

Comment: This should work

Comment: I tried above but this didn't worked